# How is the voltage split?

Tags: analog, converter, output, dual

Can anyone please explain how from +VO which is 5V and -Vo which is -5V, at the output VDDL is +6V and VEEL is -4V?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The module output is isolated 10V so you can set it to any potential you want.

Here the potential is set by using the Zener diode, as it will have approximately 6.2V over it when current flows through it.

Since the Zener anode is connected to ground which by definition is 0V, so the cathode will be at approximately 6.2V and the rest of the voltage will be over the Zener bias resistor.